# Deploy Websocket Client in Wildfly 13

Tags: wildfly, java-websocket, wildfly-13

I'm trying to deploy a Camel Route that use a Webscoket client as a consumer in Wildfly 13.

When I try to run the project I got the follow error:

```
Caused by: [java.lang.RuntimeException - Could not find an implementation class.]: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find an implementation class.
        at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainerImpl(ContainerProvider.java:89)
        at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:69)
```

I'm using the follow depencencies:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
 <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
 <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Running the code on Eclipse, everything works fine.

I need to do some specific configuration on Wildfly or in the project to run this code?

My Maven build:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
            <customClasspathLayout>META-INF</customClasspathLayout>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from your description what's wrong with you particular setup, but generally, the easiest way to write Camel integrations on top of WildFly is to use WildFly Camel: https://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/#_getting_started

Websockets are supported via Undertow component. For a simple route like the following

```
from("undertow:ws://localhost:8080/my-app")
    .log("Message received from WebSocket Client : ${body}")
```

you'd need just the undertow-component dependency (note the `provided` scope):

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-camel-bom</artifactId>
                <version><!-- your WF Camel version --></version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-undertow</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of WildFly Camel

Comment: Hi @Peter Pelaga, thanks for your answer. I was able to solve this issue today.
Just added the file: META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider and provide the value: io.undertow.websockets.jsr.UndertowContainerProvider. Problema was solved, but now I'm facing SSL Problem.